# Getting rid of Keyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can't get my keyboard to go away when I press the return key in iOS. I have  in my header file, I am setting self.textField.delegate = self; and I have implemented the following:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:UITextField *)textField {
[textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

At first it wouldn't do anything when I pressed enter, but now, after connecting the Did End on Exit to the View Controller with the Connections Inspector I am getting an NSInvalidArgumentException reason -[ViewController dismissKeyboard:]:
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155e10620.

Any ideas? 
I am using Xcode 6.1. I connected the Did End On Exit to the View Controller in which the textField lies and when I released the connection a small button appeared that said originText on it and I selected that since it was the only option.

Here is my code (abbreviated) -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) CBCentralManager *centralManager;

@property (strong, nonatomic) CBPeripheral *discoveredPerepheral;
@property (strong) CBUUID *myServiceUUID;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData *data;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *originText;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *destText;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVSpeechSynthesizer *synth;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVSpeechUtterance *utter;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *charLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *isConnected;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myPeripherals;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *aLabel;
- (IBAction)originText:(id)sender;

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;


@end



#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property int myInt;

@end

@implementation ViewController

bool isConnected = NO;
CBCharacteristic *originChar;
CBUUID *originUUID;
NSString *const tempUUID = @"0499F5DB-DDC6-4BEF-B551-EB69F9254BB9";

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle     *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self     queue:nil options:nil];
_data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
originUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"0499F5DB-DDC6-4BEF-B551-EB69F9254BB9"];
_myServiceUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"16055ED2-606D-47D4-B4C0-8F6BFC903DAB"];
_synth = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
[_originText setDelegate:self];
[_destText setDelegate:self];
_originText.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyGo;
```

}
...

```
- (IBAction)originText:(id)sender {
    if (isConnected) {
        NSData *dataToWrite = [_originText.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        //[_discoveredPerepheral writeValue:dataToWrite forCharacteristic:originChar type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
        NSLog(@"Data Written.");
    }
    NSLog(@"Disconnected.");
}


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"HEy Hey");
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you declaring your class as conforming to the keyboard delegate?

Comment: I think so. I am using UITextFieldDelegate in the header file if that's what you mean. Past that, I'm not sure.

Comment: Is the textField named textField?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed more code. Where are you calling `dismissKeyboard`? What are you connecting the Did End on Exit to? What version of iOS are you encountering this error on? Also, please copy and paste the code to avoid the typos and errors such as the ones you have in the code posted now.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in `textFieldSouldReturn`. Thus, this delegate method was never invoked.

Answer (score 0):

```
  -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:UITextField *)textField {
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Sometimes that works better as it doesn't matter which control is currently the first responder.

Comment: Really? a down vote 12 seconds after I posted the answer. Not even enough time for you to have tried the code.

Comment: It wasn't me that down voted, although I don't think this is the problem. I'm assuming that you mean to put that where [textField resignFirstResponder] is and my code is not reaching that point. It's throwing the exception when it calls textFieldShouldReturn. I put comment inside the method before execution reaches resignFirstResponder and the NSlog is not printing.

Comment: I didn't down vote but perhaps someone did because your answer makes attempt to answer the question. While using `endEditing:` is a valid way to clear the keyboard, it makes no attempt to help the OP understand the problem they are having with a method that should work.

Comment: I assumed the `textFieldShouldReturn` method was being called and that the errors were just typos. Ie, the method spelling error, the missing `(`, and no return value. `dismissKeyboard` is only available on iOS 8, so you would get an `unrecognized selector` error on an iOS 7 device if that's what you're testing on.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `UITextFieldDelegate` in your .h file and then in .m file, use  `self.textField.delegate = self`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove both the declarations of textField from your .h file, they might be confusing the compiler and overwriting the delegate methods. Also, get rid of your Did End on Exit  connection as it is unnecessary for managing the keyboard.